# MAMP Mysql server not working. Error message 2002

Tags: mysql, sockets, mamp

Had not used `MAMP` in a year since install, opened ok yesterday, was in phpmyadmin, then did other things on computer (just on MS Word, and checked news on Internet), then went back to MAMP.

Problems:

1. click MAMP icon, "open start page" is greyed out so can't click & won't open.
2. Apache server is checked, but MySql server is not checked.
3. "Start servers" will not start the MySql server....
4. When I go to http://localhost/MAMP/ I get this error:

> 2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)  The server is not
>   responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Upon research I saw to do this:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

It gave me this message:

```
ln: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock: File exists
```

But when I go to this file & click:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

It says:

```
The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “mysql.sock” can’t be found.
```

Have even reinstalled MAMP & same problems. Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step1: check if mysql is already running in background if running but you are not able to connect then kill it.

ps -ef | grep mysql  ---to check if any mysql process is running
kill -9 process_id --getting from above command if any.

Step2: delete if mysql.sock file exists.

Step3: now start mysql service.

Step4: If still getting same issue then share mysqld.log details.

Comment: When I type: ps -ef | grep mysql,  then I get: 501 63601 29773   0 12:00AM ttys000    0:00.01 grep mysql. Not sure what that means.

Comment: means mysql is not running, so try to follow step2 and 3 if still get same issue then share output as per step4.

Comment: Did step 2 & 3. Mysql server still not working. How to share mysqld.log?

Comment: Opened MAMP again but it won't let me start mysql server (Apache server is on). How do I get logs?

Comment: may be here > /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err

Comment: When I copy/paste that log into Word it's like 58 pages. What am I looking for or what can I copy/paste on here to show?

Comment: This seems to be error, just repeating & repeating (here's first part): 150704 19:59:43 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150704 19:59:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
150704 19:59:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
150704 19:59:44 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
150704 19:59:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150704 19:59:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

Comment: Here's next part: 150704 19:59:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150704 19:59:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150704 19:59:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150704 19:59:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile1 is of different size 0 5242888 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
150704 19:59:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150704 19:59:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Comment: Here's last part: 150704 19:59:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150704 19:59:44 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: provide latest entry today's date and timestamp when you try to restarted your mysql last time.

Comment: error seems innodb realted parameter, you can set innodb_buffer_pool_size value more than 1 gb and upto 80% of your total RAM

Comment: 150706 00:12:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
150706 00:29:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
150706  0:29:01 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
150706  0:29:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

Comment: 150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile1 is of different size 0 5242888 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Aborting
150706  0:29:01 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: 150706 00:29:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

Comment: How to do that? "you can set innodb_buffer_pool_size value more than 1 gb and upto 80% of your total RAM"

Comment: take help from here "http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/02/how-to-set-mysql-default-storage-engine.html" you can set this variable also in mysqld section

Comment: That link says: "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist." How to set this variable also in mysqld section?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but might be useful to someone.
Quick solution that worked form me:

1. Quit MAMP.
2. In the finder go to **Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/** and **delete** the last log file (look for a file named **ib_logfileN** – being N the log number). Please back up these before you delete them
3. **Restart MAMP**.

Source: https://juanfra.me/2013/01/mysql-not-starting-mamp-fix/